# Como usar debug sip no asterisk?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, sip

No software Asterisk, é possível efetuar um debug de um numero de telefone somente? sem ele ser peer do do meu server?

sei que existe os comandos:

```
    sip set debug peer 1000
    sip set debug ip 172.16.0.100
```

de modo similar ao debug é possivel fazer o controle do verbose para somente um usuario?

caso não seja possível existe algum modo padronizado para fazer testes desse tipo em produção? para filtrar chamadas incomming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, tentarei responder as perguntas por partes.

**1- No software Asterisk, é possível efetuar um debug de um numero de telefone somente? sem ele ser peer do do meu server?**

Você pode filtrar pelo IP deste peer, como você já sabe, mas se isto não for suficiente você pode utilizar o wireshark e filtrar a capturas por chamadas voip, por ip de origem, destino, conteúdo do pacote (filtrando por peer, por exemplo) etc.

Sugestão de leitura: [Wireshark - Voip Calls](https://wiki.wireshark.org/VoIP_calls)

**2- de modo similar ao debug é possível fazer o controle do verbose para somente um usuario?**

Sim, mas pelo log ao invés do CLI. Você pode filtrar as chamadas para somente um usuário pelo log do asterisk, desde que o log do tipo 'verbose' esteja habilitado no /etc/asterisk/logger.conf
Exemplo:

```
full => notice,warning,error,verbose,dtmf,fax
```

A partir do asterisk 11 toda chamada possui um identificador (*call-id*) que possibilita o rastreamento dela no log. Exemplo:

```
[2017-04-11 09:17:02] VERBOSE[50999][C-00000620] pbx.c: Executing [1234@CONTEXTO-PADRAO:1] NoOp("SIP/PEERQUALQUER-00000507", "### RECEBENDO CHAMADA DE 1234567890 PARA 1234 ###") in new stack
```

Na linha acima é possível ver que o asterisk recebeu uma chamada do peer PEERQUALQUER para a extensão 1234. Todas as linhas desta chamada tem o identificador [C-00000620] que pode ser filtrado com um 'grep', por exemplo:

```
grep "C-00000620" /var/log/asterisk/full
```

Sugestão de leitura: [Call Identifier Logging](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Call+Identifier+Logging)

**3- caso não seja possível existe algum modo padronizado para fazer testes desse tipo em produção? para filtrar chamadas incomming**

Eu utilizo os dados do arquivo de log para filtrar e analizar fluxo chamadas entrantes. Quando quero mais detalhes, principalmente de sinalização, utilizo o [sngrep](https://github.com/irontec/sngrep/wiki/Installing-Binaries) para analise em tempo real das mensagens, diálogos e transações SIP. Utilizo o wireshark para análise de arquivos pcap quando não preciso de análise em tempo real.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o **SNGREP** para monitorar direto no terminal tem uma saída muito detalhada, ela for projetada para monitorar trafego SIP.

É uma ferramenta leve e muito util no dia a dia, segue o gitbub do projeto.

https://github.com/irontec/sngrep